# Java mail attachment raw content appended to mail body and not as file

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am sending mail with pdf file as attachment, the mail sent is received with the mail raw content i.e with all

```
Please find the attached file.

Best Regards ,
Smith
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="----=_Part_0_73109.1402484524135"

------=_Part_0_73109.1402484524135
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Dear Sir ,

Please find the attached file.

Best Regards ,
Smith

------=_Part_0_73109.1402484524135
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=QuoteStatment_1402408005919.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=QuoteStatment_1402408005919.pdf

JVBERi0xLjQKJcfl9OXwCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0ZpbHRlciAvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUKL0xlbmd0aCA2
OTAxCj4+CnN0cmVhbQp42u1d/XPbNrb9uf4rMLPt223GUQkQIADP7MxTZDlR15YcS2nabXfesDYT
q6uvSnQS969ffokARZoCokvqdTZNE8tXwuE5uOARyQuCv5/8fvKV0+Fo+/fm5Yn+6/r9CUZO9Cf+

------=_Part_0_73109.1402484524135--
```

exposed and the file content append to mail body.

Following is high level view on operation performed before sending mail

1. Retrieve html file via webservice (which would be in Base64 encode )
2. Decode to String object, passed to pd4ml for pdf generation as byte[]
3. byte[] attachment is added to Multipart(MIMEBodyPart)

Am using java mail 1.4.7 API, JDK 1.6. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Here is the mailing code snippet

```
public boolean sendEmail(String to_recipients, String cc_recipients, String subject, String bodyHTMLContent, 
        byte[] attachmentContentByteArr, String attachmentFileName) throws QuoteToPDFEmailerException{
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("sendEmail(String[], String, String, String, byte[], String) - start"); 
    }

    boolean mailSent = Boolean.FALSE;
    boolean debug = Boolean.FALSE;

    Session session=null;


    try {

        session = EmailHandler.configureMailerSession();

        String debugFlagStr=(resource.getValue("mail.debug"));

        String auth=resource.getValue("mail.smtp.auth");

        if(EmailHandler.password==null || EmailHandler.password.isEmpty())
        {
            logger.warn("password is empty");
        }

        if(debugFlagStr.equalsIgnoreCase(UtilityConstants.STR_TRUE))
        {
            debug = Boolean.TRUE;
        }

        session.setDebug(debug);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(fromAdd);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

        if (to_recipients != null && !to_recipients.isEmpty()) {

            String[] recipientArr = to_recipients.split(";");

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipientArr.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < recipientArr.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipientArr[i]);
            }

            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            if(cc_recipients != null && !cc_recipients.isEmpty()){
                String[] cc_recipientArr = cc_recipients.split(";");

                InternetAddress[] addressCC = new InternetAddress[cc_recipientArr.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < cc_recipientArr.length; i++) {
                    addressCC[i] = new InternetAddress(cc_recipientArr[i]);
                }

                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, addressCC);
            }

            msg.setSubject(subject);

            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            htmlPart.setContent(bodyHTMLContent, (resource.getValue("interface.bodyHTMLContent")));
            mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

            if (attachmentContentByteArr != null && attachmentContentByteArr.length > 0) {
                logger.info("File Name For The Attachments : "+attachmentFileName);
                MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();                   
                if(!attachmentFileName.endsWith(UtilityConstants.PDF_FILE_DOT_EXTENSION))
                    attachmentFileName = attachmentFileName.concat(UtilityConstants.PDF_FILE_DOT_EXTENSION);

                attachment.setFileName(attachmentFileName);
                attachment.setContent(attachmentContentByteArr, "application/pdf");
                mp.addBodyPart(attachment);
            }

            msg.setContent(mp);

            SMTPTransport smtpTransport = EmailHandler.getConnectedSMTPTransport(auth);

            smtpTransport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));

            mailSent = Boolean.TRUE;
            logger.info("Email sent to recipient successfully");

        }


    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(MessageConfiguration.getMessage(Quote2PDF_EmailAssistConstants.ERROR_MSG_09), e);
        throw new QuoteToPDFEmailerException(MessageConfiguration.getMessage(Quote2PDF_EmailAssistConstants.ERROR_MSG_09), e);
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("sendEmail(String[], String, String, String, byte[], String) - end"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    return mailSent;
}
```

Comment: What way (and where) do you see the raw message? This is what a mailmessage looks like when sent over SMTP.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  What you have above is mostly a correct MIME message, although I don't know where the first 4 lines came from; perhaps an editing error in your post?